# JndiException when using Hibernate 4.0 with Tomcat 7 when using persistence.xml

Tags: java, hibernate, tomcat, jpa, jndi

I'm using Hibernate 4.0 with a JPA persistence.xml file on Tomcat 7.  No Struts, just straight Hibernate with some Jersey services.  Here is the exception I'm running into:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.service.jndi.JndiException: Unable to lookup JNDI name [jdbc/MyDB]
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:68)
    at org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:116)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:159)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory.buildSettings(SettingsFactory.java:71)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettingsInternal(Configuration.java:2273)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSettings(Configuration.java:2269)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1738)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:904)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name jdbc is not bound in this Context
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:820)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:154)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:135)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:396)
    at org.hibernate.service.jndi.internal.JndiServiceImpl.locate(JndiServiceImpl.java:65)
    ... 23 more
```

I see the note about jbc is not bound in this context, but I'm confused as how this is happening.  I'm deploying my context in an app-specific context.xml, below:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/MyDB" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              maxActive="100" maxIdle="30" maxWait="10000"
              username="..." password="..." driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
              url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb"/>
</Context>
```

And my persistence.xml file looks like:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="com.example.mysql" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/MyDB</non-jta-data-source>
        <class>...</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.datasource" value="jdbc/MyDB"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.id.new_generator_mappings" value ="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Finally, my web.xml file has the resource defined as so:

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>My Web Application</display-name>
    <resource-ref>
        <description>DB Connection</description>
        <res-ref-name>jdbc/MyDB</res-ref-name>
        <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
        <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    </resource-ref>
...
</web-app>
```

As for my layout, here is how my war file is structured:

```
app.war
    + META-INF
        - context.xml
    + WEB-INF
        + classes
            + META-INF
                - persistence.xml
        + lib
        - web.xml
```

A few minor notes:

- Using a global context versus an application-specific context makes no difference.
- The code trying to instantiate an EntityManager instance is in a JAR file in the lib directory (part of a multi-project Maven build), but the persistence XML is in the main web app as outlined above.
- I can see the JNDI datasource in Tomcat and I can query it using [psi-probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/), i.e. I can access the connection information and successfully execute SQL queries against the data source.

Comment: Your persistence.xml has <non-jta-data-source>jdbc/AxonifyDB</...>.  You need to bind that as a resource in your context.xml.

Comment: Bah, spelling mistake on my part.  I was trying to obfuscate the files.  :-)  The names all match actually.

Comment: Are there any errors in your Tomcat logs?  Can you look at the jndi tree in your Tomcat admin?  If so, do you see jdbc/MyDB?

Comment: According to [psi-probe](http://code.google.com/p/psi-probe/), I can see the datasource, test the connection and execute some SQL statements successfully.  I still get errors in my hibernate code where I cannot create my entity manager.

Comment: Where do you create your EntityManager?  In a spring xml?  That should take a db connection pointing to your jndi base connection, using a session factory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you use a portable resource with , you should call your JNDI using "java:comp/env/your_resource", like java:comp/env/jdbc/MyDB

Comment: Thanks, that seems to be working.  I'm getting a different exception now, but that may be due to a different config issue.

Comment: A quick update for those who may stumble across this issue.  This only occurs if you are using Tomcat < 7.0.27.  If you use 7.0.27 or later, they have fixed a problem for JNDI resource lookups that causes this error.  Took me about a day to figure out why my machine was working but my Ubuntu 12.04 boxes were not.